# Why can't I access images deployed via a mapped folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, image

I have deployed some images to the SharePoint server using an Visual Studio Images mapped folder in a project .

Using Windows Explorer I can see they have been deployed here:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES\LegalStuff
```

However, if I attempt to view them via the browser, I just get a 404.

I can access this standard icon via the browser and from an ascx control:

```
<SharePoint site>/_layouts/images/siteIcon.png
```

but not this:

```
<SharePoint site>/_layouts/images/256_FOLDER.png
```

and not my deployed images in the `LegalStuff` folder:

```
<SharePoint site>/_layouts/images/LegalStuff/inbox.png
```

Any ideas why this should be so? I have full Admin privileges on the server, and have deployed a number of complex SharePoint features etc. with no previous issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 2013 you need to add `/15/`to the url, like so:

```
/_layouts/15/images/LegalStuff/inbox.png
```

Regarding the fact that some images works without the `/15/`parts, that is because they are also present in the `14` directory